# Why isn't my function being called in this example for my calculator html code?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
Memory = "0";
Current = "0";
Operation = 0;
MAXLENGTH = 30;
alert("yea");

function AddDigit(digit) {
  alert("yea");
  if (Current.length > MAXLENGTH) {
    Current = "Aargh! Too long";
  } else {
    if (eval(Current) == 0) {
      Current = dig;
    } else {
      Current = Current + dig;
    }
  }
}

document.Calculator.Display.value = Current;
}
```

```html
<FORM name="Calculator">
  <table border="3">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input type="text" maxlength="40" size="30" name="Display">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="7"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="8"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="9"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="+"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button onclick="AddDigit(4)">4</button></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="5"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="6"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="-"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="2"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="3"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="*"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="0"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="."></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="="></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="/"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="C"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="MR"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="M-"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="M+"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="MC"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
</FORM>
```

I was wondering why nothing was showing in my display when I press the 4 button in my calculator.

In the web browser bar I just see `display=` and then nothing shows in the actual display.  I added the `alert("yea")` to check if the function was even running and it didn't even run on click.

So I have no clue what is happening here.

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove `}` before `display.value` in `javascript code`

you change`<input type="button" onclick="AddDigit(4)" value="4">` insted of `<button onclick="AddDigit(4)">4</button>`

and also change `dig variable` in javascript to `digit`

```js
Memory = "0";
Current = "0";
Operation = 0;
MAXLENGTH = 30;
alert("yea");

function AddDigit(digit) {
  alert("yea");
  if (Current.length > MAXLENGTH) {
    Current = "Aargh! Too long";
  } else {
    if (eval(Current) == 0) {
      Current = digit;

    } else {
      Current = Current + digit;

    }
  }
  document.Calculator.Display.value = Current;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<script src="./calculator.js"></script>
<FORM name="Calculator">
  <table border="3">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input type="text" maxlength="40" size="30" name="Display">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="7"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="8"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="9"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="+"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="button" onclick="AddDigit(4)" value="4"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="5"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="6"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="-"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="2"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="3"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="*"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="0"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="."></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="="></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="/"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="C"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="MR"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="M-"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="M+"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="MC"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
</FORM>

</html>
```